# c# public class that can only be instantiated by its parent

Tags: c#, oop

Is it possible to have a nested class that is public but can only be instantiated by it's parent class
  e.g.

```
 public class parent
{
    public class child
    {
        public string someValue;
    }

    public child getChild()
    {
        return new child();
    }
}
```

in this example the 'child' class could be instantiated by code external to 'parent' . I want  the external code to be able to view the 'child' type but not be able to construct it's own one.

e.g

```
var someChild = new parent.child();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Make a public interface.
2. Make the child class private.
3. Make the child implement the interface.
4. Have the `getChild` method make a new child and return the interface type.

As mentioned in the comments and other answers, you can also change the access modifier on the constructor(s) of the inner class to either internal or private while leaving the inner class itself public.

Comment: +1; also an `internal` constructor on the nested class might be appropriate as well; yes it doesn't block code within the assembly creating instances - but normally it's code in other assemblies that have to be held back

Answer (score 4):

Define an internal empty constructor

```
public class child     
{         
    internal child() {}
    public string someValue;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the creation to your assembly by setting the protection level of your constructor (of the child class) to `internal`.

Or interface as told by @Servy.