# in c# can I make a function that returns a type that can only be instantiated by my class?

Tags: c#

I know I can do this:

```cs
   public class Parent
   {
       public interface IChild {}

       private class Child : IChild {}

       private int _count;

       public IChild Create()
       {
          _count++;
          return new Child();
       } 

       public void Return( IChild value )
       {
          _count--;
       }
   }
```

In this rather contrived example, I've locked it down so that Child can't be created by anyone else - but the problem is - IChild can.  So someone could return to me an ichild that I didn't create.

I can use "internal" to protect against other projects, and return a class with an internal constructor... fine - so if I'm writing a library, I can protect against other people... but I'm wondering if it's possible to protect against everything even in the same library.

is it possible for a class to have a function that returns something, class or interface that *everyone can see - but only that class can create*.

Comment: `IChild` is an interface. If you don't want _any_ type that implements the interface as the parameter for `Return()`, don't ask for the interface.

Comment: As gunr said, why do you take an interface? That aside, this looks like it can be solved with just a `if (value is Child)` check (?)

Comment: I have a feeling OP is following this advice, and I'm not sure I like it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620179/1043380

Comment: Is it 100% unacceptable for anyone else besides the Parent class to instantiate a Child object, or is it that only the Parent class _knows_ how to properly instantiate it (correct constructor parameters, initial state of properties, etc)?

Comment: go with the first one - I don't want anyone instantiating it.    But really it's not for a real use case, because there are plenty of better ways to get the same effect - what I'm wondering is _is it possible_

Comment: Yes it is possible.  You cant create a `DataReader` yet the NET Framework library can return one you can use.  The constructor is not public; there is no need to 'hide' the object as a child/nested class

Comment: is that just using internal, or is there actually some way of hiding the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make `IChild` also `IDisposable` so that you can then make `Return` private and have it called when you dispose of the child. So, in other words, you don't call `Return` directly, you just dispose of the child when you're done.

```
public class Parent
{
    public interface IChild : IDisposable { }

    private class Child : IChild
    {
        private Parent parent;
        public Child(Parent parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            parent.Return(this);
        }
    }

    private int _count;

    public IChild Create()
    {
        _count++;
        return new Child(this);
    }

    private void Return(IChild value)
    {
        _count--;
    }
}
```

Now you'd use it like this:

```
var parent = new Parent();
using (var child = parent.Create())
{
    // Do something with child
    // "`Return` it on `.Dispose()`
}
```

This enables the calling code to be in control of returning the child without being able to return the wrong children.

Please note that I did not implement the disposable pattern correctly and instead opted for minimal code to demonstrate how the pattern works.

Comment: If `Return()` is private, then couldn't the parameter be the Child class rather than the interface?

Comment: this, and the return - were really just examples trying to explain the thing - I'm not really trying to achieve any business result here - I'm just trying to figure out whether it's actually possible to do... I've tried a number of things - and they all sort of feel close, but all fall down in some way.     (and obviously for a particular definition of possible - I can have a private constructor and create it with reflection inside the class for instance :))

Comment: @gunr2171 - Yes, it doesn't matter, but certainly.